# Easy way to group custom defined types to use for reference?

Tags: jsonschema

How to reference types by group instead of doing it individually?

For example here, I want "sum" and "subtract" types to accept types that are "number"-related types only("number", "sum", "subtract"). While "concatenate" can accept both "number" and "string"-related types. Including their selves. This will be really helpful for me if in case I added more types and want them to be automatically included.

```
"sum": {
  "title": "sum",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "values": {
      "type": "array",
      "items": {
        "anyOf": [
          {
            "type": "number"
          },
          {
            "$ref": "#/definitions/sum"
          },
          {
            "$ref": "#/definitions/subtract"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  "required": [
    "values"
  ]
},
"subtract": {
  "title": "subtract",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "minuend": {
      "type": "number"
    },
    "subtrahend": {
      "type": "number"
    }
  },
  "required": [
    "minuend",
    "subtrahend"
  ]
},
"concatenate": {
  "title": "concatenate",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "strings": {
      "type": "array",
      "items": {
        "anyOf": [
          {
            "type": "number"
          },
          {
            "type": "string"
          },
          {
            "$ref": "#/definitions/sum"
          },
          {
            "$ref": "#/definitions/subtract"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  "required": [
    "strings"
  ]
}
}
```

Here's the full schema:

```
    {
  "definitions": {
    "sum": {
      "title": "sum",
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "values": {
          "type": "array",
          "items": {
            "anyOf": [
              {
                "type": "number"
              },
              {
                "$ref": "#/definitions/sum"
              },
              {
                "$ref": "#/definitions/subtract"
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      "required": [
        "values"
      ]
    },
    "subtract": {
      "title": "subtract",
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "minuend": {
          "type": "number"
        },
        "subtrahend": {
          "type": "number"
        }
      },
      "required": [
        "minuend",
        "subtrahend"
      ]
    },
    "concatenate": {
      "title": "concatenate",
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "strings": {
          "type": "array",
          "items": {
            "anyOf": [
              {
                "type": "number"
              },
              {
                "type": "string"
              },
              {
                "$ref": "#/definitions/sum"
              },
              {
                "$ref": "#/definitions/subtract"
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      "required": [
        "strings"
      ]
    }
  },
  "title": "Step",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "value": {
      "oneOf": [
        {
          "type": "number",
          "minimum": 0
        },
        {
          "$ref": "#/definitions/sum"
        },
        {
          "$ref": "#/definitions/subtract"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you edit your code snippet to show where in the full schema this comes from, please?  It'll help provide a better answer.

Comment: @gregsdennis I added the schema to my question. Thank you!

Comment: It generally looks like you've defined what you want.  Are you getting an unexpected result somewhere?

Comment: @gregsdennis I want to group the custom types whether they are "numeric" or "string", and use them as parameter value for the properties of other types. For example, "sum" can accept an array of "number", "subtract" type, and even "sum" type. Same with "subtract", the "minuend" and "subtrahend" can accept any of these "numeric" types. On the other hand, "string" types can accept "string" and these "numeric" types. Sorry if I can't explain that much, because english is not my primary language.

Comment: I understand what you _want_ to do, and it looks like you're set up correctly to do that.  What isn't working?